# UDSonIP vehicle announcement

Tags: tcp, udp, ethernet, ipv4, uds

how to get the ip address of ECU from vehicle announcement in UDSonIP?

hi
as my understanding vehicle announcement is the first step of UDSonIP client server communication this is using UDP .
from vehicle announcement we get to know about other connected ECU's . in vehicle identification payload VIN,EID,GID and logical address are mentioned and logical address size is 2byte. but for storing ip address 4 byte is required ???  i have a doubt, is this logical address is same as ip address of that ECU?
how to get the ip address of target ECU in UDSonIP??

regards,
aneesh